# VBA Positive For loop, negative step

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Test1()
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 1 To 3 Step 1 'STEP POSITIVE ONE
    Next
    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

Yields 4, as expected.

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim a As Integer
    For a = 1 To 3 Step -1 'STEP NEGATIVE ONE
    Next
    Debug.Print a
End Sub
```

Why does stepping "outside" the loop result in 1?

Why does VBA step out-of-bounds for Test1, but stop stepping when it goes out-of-bonuds for Test2?

EDIT:
In addition to the above, running `For a = 1 To 1 Step 1` results in 2, and `For a = 1 To 1 Step -1` results in 0.

`For a = 1 To 2 Step 1` results in 3, but `For a = 1 To 2 Step -1` results in 1.

Comment: Because the second loop does not execute even once. Try the way it should be, `For a = 3 To 1 Step -1`.

Comment: Say it out loud, i want to step from 1 to 3 by stepping backwards -1 each time. Doesn't sound right does it?

Comment: I know what I'm doing, I'm just curious as to why what happens happens. `For a = 1 To 3 Step 1` steps once more after reaching 3, but `For a = 1 To 3 Step -1` never even steps.

Comment: @leetdavid that is because the logic doesn't make sense. You cannot go from 1 to 3, by steps of -1 (you can however go from 3 to 1, which is what you should write if you want to go backwards).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `Test1` (i.e. `For a = 1 To 3 Step 1`), after the 3rd time through the loop, `a` is incremented to 4. As that is greater than 3, it stops and displays 4.

In `Test2` (i.e. `For a = 1 To 3 Step -1`), `a` is initially set to 1. As that is already less than 3, it immediately stops and displays 1.

In `For a = 1 To 1 Step 1`, `a` is set to 1, which is not greater than 1, so the loop proceeds and then `a` is incremented to 2. As 2 is greater than 1, it stops and displays 2.

In `For a = 1 To 1 Step -1`, `a` is set to 1, which is not less than 1, so the loop proceeds and then `a` is decremented to 0. As 0 is less than 1, it stops and displays 0.

In `For a = 1 To 2 Step 1`, `a` is set to 1, which is not greater than 2, so the loop proceeds and then `a` is incremented to 2, and then `a` is incremented to 3. As 3 is greater than 1, it stops and displays 3.

In `For a = 1 To 2 Step -1`, `a` is set to 1, which is less than 2, so the loop stops and displays 1.

---

The actual process in these loops is:

- Initialise the loop counter to the "start value"
- Loop over the following steps:

  - Determine whether the loop counter is greater than the "end value" (if "step" is positive or zero) or less than the "end value" (if "step" is negative) and, if so, exit the loop
  - Perform statements within the loop
  - Add "step" to the loop counter

This is all documented on the MSDN page re the ["For...Next Statement"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/fornext-statement).

Comment: Friendly hint: in the `Step -1` cases variable a is set to 1, but exits further loops as the mathematical condition 1 to e.g. 2 or 3 (positive n) counting upwards by negative steps  is a "mission impossible" case, not because the starting value is lower than the upper bound . BTW you can stop the counter at any (wanted) item WITHIN the loop by `Exit For` (one can also assign true or false to a boolean variable therein to check if a loop has been done or something has been found).

Comment: @T.M. It does exit because the starting value is lower that the upper bound, not because it detects a mission impossible case. It is all documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/fornext-statement). From the negative `Step`, the loop assumes `counter >= end` (see the little table) which immediately fails. The next sentence then documents that the counter is incremented only "After all statements in the loop have executed", which is why it does not happen when the loop does not execute at least once.

Comment: @GSerg, a) the counter a is initialized with the start value, b) there is expressed an absolute pre-condition in the mentioned table heading: *"LOOP EXECUTES IF"*, in the case of negative steps if `counter >= end`. Thus there is NO further loop at all, mission impossible. Only after actual loop execution, step is added to counter. You can test this by inserting some Debug.Prints, if there is any further loop execution. See, if a loop would have been actually executed by "adding" - negative - steps to the counter, excecution would never end in the examples above.

Comment: @T.M. The "pre-condition" in that table isn't a **pre**-condition - it is exactly the same test that is performed at the start of **each** iteration. (And, AFAIK, the start of each iteration is the only point where a test is performed.)  But, in what you call the "mission impossible" case, that test fails at the start of the very first iteration and therefore the statements within the loop never get executed even once.

Comment: @T.M. You basically restated what I said, but apparently thinking it's different to what you are now saying (and apparently that I said that loop increment happens, which I did not). I was specifically addressing your "*exits further loops as ...  counting upwards by negative steps is a "mission impossible" case, **not** because the starting value is lower than the upper bound*". That is not true. Like it is documented, the loop exits without incrementing the counter *specifically because* `counter >= end` does not hold, which *is* "because the starting value is lower than the upper bound".

Comment: Thank you. Explaining the loop process helped me understand why this happens.

Comment: @GSerg, appreciate your hints and apologize as I got on the wrong track in some essential parts and simply misunderstood your arguments.  I agree completely with YowE3K ‘s  clarifications.

Comment: @YowE3K Thank you for your helpful clarifications as to the testing process where I apparently got on the wrong track - one never stops learning.

Comment: @T.M. I always consider it a bad day if I don't learn at least one new thing from Stack Overflow! :)